# IBM Watson Speech To Text API returns error 403

Tags: ibm-watson, websphere

i am trying to call IBM STT Api with this code:

```
        String auth = new IamAuthenticator("AuthApi").requestToken().getAccessToken();


        client = new WebSocketClient(new URI(String.format("wss://%s/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?access_token=%s",uri,auth))) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
                clientInterface.OnOpen();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                clientInterface.OnMessage(message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
                clientInterface.OnClose();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception ex) {
                clientInterface.OnError(ex);
            }
        };
```

But i always get this: Invalid status code received: 403 Status line: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.
any help? 
Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason for using only half of the SDK - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=java#websocket_methods ?

Comment: I want to send PCM audio from microphone (Android) in streaming and the standard SDK doesn't have this option